# Использование distinct для подсчета кол-ва

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql

Добрый день.
Есть такая структура:

```
id   | date
1    | 01.01.2017
2    | 01.01.2017
1    | 02.01.2017
3    | 02.01.2017
4    | 03.01.2017
1    | 03.01.2017
2    | 04.01.2017
5    | 04.01.2017
5    | 05.01.2017
2    | 05.01.2017
.......
```

Необходимо получить консолидированные данные с накопительным итогов, а именно:

```
date       | count
01.01.2017 | 2
02.01.2017 | 3
03.01.2017 | 4
04.01.2017 | 5
05.01.2017 | 5
```

T.е. за каждую уникальную дату необходимо взять сумму уникальных ID с накопительным итогом. 
Знаю, как это можно сделать написав функцию. Но перебором делать подобную задачу не верно. Как можно сделать это одним запросом?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вариант с оконными функциями, оценочная стоимость postgresql 100 против 20000 в варианте с явным подсчетом всех строк от начала до каждой даты:

```
select date, max(cnt)
  from (
   select A.date, count(B.id) over(order by A.date) cnt
     from (select distinct date from tdtab) A
     left join (
       select id, min(date) date
         from tdtab
        group by id
    ) B on B.date=A.date
  ) X
 group by date
```

Время выполнения обоих вариантов, конечно стоит сравнить на реальных данных

Comment: Отлично, то что нужно. Спасибо

Answer (score 4):

```
select d.date, count(distinct t.id) from
(select distinct date date from t) d
join t on t.date<=d.date
group by d.date;
```

Comment: Я приводил в описании структуру, которую необходимо получить. В ней присутствует не только кол-во элементов, но еще и поле дата. Ваш запрос возвращает только кол-во элементов, причем без накопительного итога.

Comment: Накопительный итог просмотрел, это да. Ответ обновил. Ну а дату-то могли бы и сами добавить ;)

Comment: Задание не соответствует примеру. Во-первых, в сабже присутствует count, аналогично названо поле в примере - но по тексту вопроса "за каждую уникальную дату необходимо взять **сумму** уникальных ID". Так количество или сумма? Во-вторых, для даты 04.01.2017 в примере показан желаемый итог count=5. В исходных данных для этой даты присутствуют две записи, с id=2 и id=5. Итоговые 5 можно получить разве что требованием вернуть максимум по id, что не соответствует ни count, ни сумме.

Думаю, нужно более внимательно проверить формулировку вопроса...

Comment: 5 за 4.01 это количество уникальных id до этой даты включительно.

Comment: Ух ты ж блин... а чего было сразу так не сформулировать?

Comment: Сколько будет выполняться ваш запрос для 1 млн записей? Это простой перебор